# iid random variables and stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, stopping-times

This is Exercise 14.30 from Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning.

Let $X_i$ be iid with $E|X| < \infty$, and let $T$ be a stopping time adapted to $\{ X_i \}$. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. If $E|S_T| = \infty$, then $E[T] = \infty$ as well.

I'm not really sure where to start. Clearly, $E[T] = \sum_{t \geq 1} t P(T = t)$, but how do I relate $P(T=t)$ to $S_T$ when I know nothing about the stopping time explicitly?

Comment: Hint: Do you know a theorem which assumes that $E(T)$ is finite and deduces some cool stuff from this hypothesis?